# /bin/sh string variable as multiple argument

Tags: shell, arguments

I have a docker container setting an ARG to

```
CMAKE_ARGS=-DWITH_CPU=arm -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad"
```

I then want to pass these into cmake as command line arguments

```
cmake ../. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib "$CMAKE_ARGS"
```

However, it fails.
I suspect due to the " or spaces.

Docker ARG can only be a string, and docker uses /bin/sh (not bash)

Please help!
Currently needing two separate dockerfiles due to this :(

I've tried single quotes, escaping quotes, "$ARG" and $ARG.
Nothing works.
cmake either sees -mvectorize-with-neon-quad as an argument or -DWITH_CPU argument as the whole string

Comment: Did you try to remove quotes?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cmake ../. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib "$CMAKE_ARGS"
> ```

Calls `cmake` with the contents of `$CMAKE_ARGS` as one argument while it seems you need to pass `-DWITH_CPU=arm`, `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad`  and `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad` as 3 separate arguments to `cmake`.

POSIX `sh` doesn't have array variable support. Its variables can only contain one value.

You can however store the values separated by one character that you know doesn't occur in the words, and use the split+glob operator (leaving a variable unquoted), disabling the glob part which you don't want to split it again

```
CMAKE_ARGS='-DWITH_CPU=arm|-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad|-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mvectorize-with-neon-quad'
IFS='|' # split on |
set -o noglob # disable globbing
cmake ../. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib $CMAKE_ARGS # split+glob
```